# Unit Testing nested command objects in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, tdd

Docs say we can test controllers with command objects just by mocking params
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers

I wonder if this works for Nested Command Objects? Has anyone gotten this to work?

Example:

**Controller**

```
def create(FormCommand form){
  form.validate()
  ...
}
```

**Command**

```
class FormCommand {
  InnerCommand cmd
}

class InnerCommand{
  String x
  static constraints ={
     x(nullable: false)
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
void testCreate(){
  params["inner.x"]="any"
  controller.create()
  ...
}
```

My expectation is that the command objects are created and data binding works, also I expect inner command to be validated. Am I expecting too much?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what are you trying to validate?

Comment: I tested here with Grails 2.2.1. Even in run-app the inner command stays null, but if you have a domain class instead of a command then it gets populated by the databinding. I sent a question to the user mails list with this behavior, as soon as I get the answer I will update here.

Comment: thanks Sergio, appreciate the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that's possible what you want, but needs some code :-)

### Data Binding

For nested command objects Grails databinding needs a not null instance of the inner command.

To do that, you can create a custom `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.BindEventListener`:

```
class InnerCommandBindEventListener împlements BindEventListener {
  public void doBind(Object target, MutablePropertyValues source, TypeConverter typeConverter) {
    target.cmd = new InnerCommand()
  }
}
```

And declare it in your **resources.groovy**

```
innerCommandBindEventListener(InnerCommandBindEventListener)
```

### Nested Validation

To resolve the validation issue, you need a custom validator for your cmd:

```
class FormCommand {
  InnerCommand cmd
  static constraints = {
    cmd nullable: false, validator: { cmd, obj ->
      // manually trigger the inner command validation
      if(!cmd.validate()) {
        return 'invalid.innercommand.message' 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio, a bit disappointing. I will give this a whirl and update if this works.

Comment: Tested, and you are right. We did do some things differently. I will post that in to the update of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if exactly applicable to the issue at hand, but for at least the data binding in tests for controller actions this works:

```
params.'player1.name' = "John"
```

Where as this gives null pointer exception:

```
params.player1.name = "John"
```

When controller is doing:

```
Game game = new Game(params)
```

And Game has:

```
Player player1
```